# Aspose - Convert Excel to PDF is Slow

Tags: java, excel, pdf, aspose

Am using Aspose and it is very slow in converting Excel to PDF.
I have generated XSSFWorkbook

```
ByteArrayOutputStream excelAsByteArrayOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
xssfWorkbook.write(out_excel);
excelAsByteArrayOutStream.close();

ByteArrayOutputStream pdfAsByteArrayOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(excelAsByteArrayOutStream.toByteArray()));
workbook.save(out, SaveFormat.PDF);
```

Any other faster way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Aspose.Cells for Java is fast and efficient to convert bigger MS Excel workbooks to PDF file format. I guess the slowness issue might be on XSSFWorkbook part which is writing byte array. Or the issue might be in the module for extracting/loading file from streams.  For confirmation, you may only use Aspose.Cells APIs (without involving XSSFWorkbook) to load the file from streams and then save to PDF file format.
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
Path fileLocation = Paths.get("your_file.xlsx");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation);

try (FileOutputStream simpleStream = new FileOutputStream("no_aspose_file.xlsx")) {
    simpleStream.write(bytes);
}
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
ByteArrayOutputStream dstStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfSaveOptions saveOptions = new PdfSaveOptions(SaveFormat.PDF);
// Save Workbook to PDF format by passing the object of PdfSaveOptions
workbook.save(dstStream, saveOptions);
..........
```

I would recommend you to try latest version/fix v19.8 which has more enhancements.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.